# BigQuery standard SQL: partition using grouped by column

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to partition using a boolean column which I also use to group by. The column is a result of applying a function, an not an organic column.

With Legacy-SQL this worked using the column name in the partition by clause. In standard SQL it's not possible to use the column name, and when re-writing the column definition an error appears.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
 corpus = 'sonnets' sonnetsCorp,
 count(distinct word) cnt,
 count(distinct word)/sum(count(distinct word)) over (partition by corpus = 'sonnets') ratio
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` 
 group by 1
```

I get an error:

```
Unrecognized name: sonnetsCorp at [5:68]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a subquery with standard SQL. Legacy SQL supports some non-standard functionality that tends to break down in corner cases.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
 sonnetsCorp,
 count(distinct word) cnt,
 count(distinct word)/sum(count(distinct word)) over (partition by sonnetsCorp) ratio
FROM (
  SELECT
   *,
   corpus = 'sonnets' AS sonnetsCorp
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
)
GROUP BY sonnetsCorp;
```

Answer (score 2):

> The column is a result of applying a function, an not an organic column.

Below is a simple way to express this case (derived column) in BigQuery Standard SQL, so the query written in Legacy SQL can be left almost as is (without introducing extra sub-query)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  sonnetsCorp,
  COUNT(DISTINCT word) cnt,
  COUNT(DISTINCT word)/SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT word)) OVER (PARTITION BY sonnetsCorp) ratio
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`, UNNEST([corpus = 'sonnets']) AS sonnetsCorp
GROUP BY sonnetsCorp
```

Above `, UNNEST([corpus = 'sonnets']) AS sonnetsCorp` looks like cross join but in reality it is just derived column calculated on row per row basis!

> With Legacy-SQL this worked using the column name in the partition by clause

Meantime, I feel like in your question you presented a query that you actually use in Legacy SQL. You might "oversimplified" it for the purpose of showing your issue with derived column - in this case ignore below. But if this query is exactly what you use  - it makes not much sense and below query does exactly the same

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  corpus = 'sonnets' AS sonnetsCorp,
  COUNT(DISTINCT word) cnt
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
GROUP BY sonnetsCorp
```

The way you constructed ratio field makes it always equal to 1!